# Why in Xamarin Android the method Statements are getting executed in Reverse order

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Why in Xamarin Android the method Statements are getting executed in Reverse order
Which means the 5 is being displayed First and then the 0 gets displayed.

I have done this

```
<Button HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Click To Connect" Clicked="Button_OnClicked"></Button>

        private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayAlert("0", "0", "OK");
            DisplayAlert("5", "5", "OK");
        }
```

Comment: first look at docs and it returns `Task` .... so it should be rather used in `async` and with `await`    like     `private async void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("0", "0", "OK");
            await DisplayAlert("5", "5", "OK");
        }`   ... and why this happening  ... it is obvious ... it's not blocking so second alert displays on top first - so you are wrong about excution order ... disclaimer: never wrote the single line with Xamarin

Comment: @selvin There is no await and async. It is just a simple c# method. Why should the below lines get executed first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DisplayAlert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/pop-ups#display-an-alert) method can also be used to capture a user's response by presenting two buttons and returning a boolean. To get a response from an alert, supply text for both buttons and await the method. After the user selects one of the options the answer will be returned to your code.

as Selvin said,if you call `DisplayAlert("0", "0", "OK");` directly,it doesn't block your thread,you don't need to wait the response from the alert,it will call `DisplayAlert("0", "0", "OK");` then call  `DisplayAlert("5", "5", "OK");`,but from the user's point of view, you see the second alert first,it overrides the first alert.

if you want display the first alert first,you should use key word `await`,it will wait for you to make a choice，then continue the second alert.

```
private async void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      await DisplayAlert("0", "0", "OK");
      await DisplayAlert("5", "5", "OK");
   }
```

Comment: I am using the DisplayAlert() to debug the Xamarin Android application. That is if something done, then tell me its done. I think there should be some other way to do the debug and error handling. Please let me know the correct way.

Comment: @BeeGees do you mean you want to get some output when you debug ?if yes,you could try to use  `Console.WriteLine("")` or `Log.Warning("", "");` then you could see it in your output

Comment: Yes absolutely right. It works. Thanx for the wonderful explanation.

Comment: There is one thing though. I am referencing .Net Standard Library project in the Xamarin project. Whenever there is an Error, I don't know how to debug it, even though I have added the Exception handling in Android. I guess because the Error is in my .Net Standard Project. So how do i go about debugging in Xamarin.